# How to change express middleware at runtime?

Tags: node.js, api, express, middleware, rate-limiting

I am trying to add a rate limiter using [express-rate-limit](https://github.com/express-rate-limit/express-rate-limit) with the ability to change the limit on runtime using an API call. Is it possible to do it?

Here are some codes to explain.

```
const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
    max: 5, // Limit each IP to 5 create account requests per `window` (here, per hour)
})

app.post('/create-account', limiter , (req, res) => {
    //...
})

app.post('/change-limit', (req, res) => {
    // Save new config to DB
    // Change the limiter middleware
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can create your own middleware that dynamically creates the `rateLimit` middleware.

Comment: From a quick glance at the documentation, you can use a function to calculate `max`. Did you try that? See https://github.com/express-rate-limit/express-rate-limit#max

Comment: @Phil - But, that only lets you change the `max` value, not the `windowMs` value or any of the other arguments to the rate limiter.  There are 15 separate options available for the rateLimiter.

Comment: @jfriend00 it wasn't clear from the question which properties OP wanted to manipulate so I was just offering a quick suggestion. It wasn't clear if OP had even read the documentation to see what was possible

Comment: @Phil - Good point.  I added a mention about the `max` callback to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to change is the max number of requests that are allowed within the configured time window, then you can do that by providing a callback function for the `max` option as described in [the doc](https://github.com/express-rate-limit/express-rate-limit#max).

But, if you want to change more than that, the software doesn't provide direct provisions to do so.  If you look at the source code, the `options` that you pass to `rateLimit()` are stored in a closure so they are not accessible after the fact to change.  But, you could do something that would create a new middleware anytime the options have been changed and have that new middleware be the one that gets called.  This involves putting a wrapper around the rateLimit middleware that can decide which actual rateLimit middleware to call.

```
// class to wrap the rateLimit middleware so that a new rate limiter
// can be substituted in at any time
class ChangeableLimiter {
    constructor(initialOptions) {
        this.createLimiter(initialOptions);
    }
    createLimiter(newOptions) {
        this.limiter = rateLimit(newOptions);
    }
    getLimiter() {
        return function (req, res, next) {
            return this.limiter(req, res, next);
        }
    }
}

const limitObj = new ChangeableLimiter({
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
    max: 5, // Limit each IP to 5 create account requests per `window` (here, per hour)
});


app.post('/create-account', limitObj.getLimiter(), (req, res) => {
    //...
})

app.post('/change-limit', (req, res) => {
    // Save new config to DB
    // Change the limiter middleware
    // construct new rateLimit options object
    const newOptions = {
     // fill this in...
    };
    limitObj.createLimiter(newOptions);
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

This makes the rate limit dynamic, by adding a wrapper around the rate limiter itself so that the middleware doesn't change, but which limiter it calls can be changed inside the wrapper.  You can then change what the rate limiter will be at any time.